# \fullcite: order of family and given names

Tags: biblatex

In my thesis I make a list of my papers in early in the document with `\fullcite`. In the list, they come out with the given name first, whereas in the bibliography they come out with family names first (as desired). I can find ways to change the order in the bibliography, but how can I change the order in the list created with `\fullcite`?

---

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[backend=biber,firstinits=true,style=authoryear-icomp,
   dashed=false,doi=false,isbn=false,url=true]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifboolexpr{%
        test {\ifentrytype{article}}%
        or
        test {\ifentrytype{inproceedings}}%
    }{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
    }
\addbibresource{bib/ex.bib}

\begin{document}
\section*{List of papers}

\noindent \fullcite{rasmussen2016a}
\bigskip \noindent \fullcite{miyakawa2009}
\bigskip \noindent \fullcite{rocard2007}

\section*{References}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

---

```
@article{winslow2009,
  title = {Et Mysterium Om Tal – Og Japanske Lektionsstudier},
  url = {https://tidsskrift.dk/index.php/mona/article/view/69263},
  number = {1},
  journaltitle = {MONA},
  urldate = {2016-01-23},
  date = {2009},
  pages = {31--43},
  author = {Winsløw, Carl},
  file = {/home/jb/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/storage/KGRFU9HA/MONA_2009-1_Et_mysterium_om_tal.pdf}
}

@article{miyakawa2009,
  title = {Didactical Designs for Students’ Proportional Reasoning: An “Open Approach” Lesson and a “Fundamental Situation”},
  volume = {72},
  shorttitle = {Didactical Designs for Students’ Proportional Reasoning},
  number = {2},
  journaltitle = {Educational Studies in Mathematics},
  date = {2009},
  pages = {199--218},
  author = {Miyakawa, Takeshi and Winsløw, Carl},
  file = {/home/jb/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/storage/7B6BKRE2/Miyakawa og Winsløw - 2009 - Didactical designs for students’ proportional reas.pdf}
}

@incollection{nohda2000,
  title = {Teaching by {{Open}}-{{Approach Method}} in {{Japanese Mathematics Classroom}}.},
  url = {http://eric.ed.gov/?id=ED466736},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 24th {{Conference}} of the {{International Group}} for the {{Psychology}} of {{Mathematics Education}}},
  urldate = {2017-04-02},
  date = {2000},
  author = {Nohda, Nobuhiko},
  file = {/home/jb/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/storage/Q8GPK94B/Nohda - 2000 - Teaching by Open-Approach Method in Japanese Mathe.pdf}
}

@book{stigler1999,
  location = {{New York}},
  title = {The {{Teaching Gap}}: {{Best Ideas}} from the {{World}}'s {{Teachers}} for {{Improving Education}} in the {{Classroom}}.},
  publisher = {{The Free Press}},
  date = {1999},
  author = {Stigler, James W. and Hiebert, James}
}

@thesis{rasmussen2016a,
  title = {Praxeologies and {{Institutional Interactions}} in the {{Advanced Science Teacher Education}}},
  url = {http://www.ind.ku.dk/publikationer/inds_skriftserie/44/44-Klaus_Rasmussen.pdf},
  institution = {{Copenhagen}},
  urldate = {2016-09-13},
  date = {2016},
  author = {Rasmussen, Klaus},
  file = {/home/jb/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/storage/VA58FM77/Rasmussen - 2016 - Praxeologies and Institutional Interactions in the.pdf}
}

@report{rocard2007,
  title = {Science Education Now: {{A}} Renewed Pedagogy for the Future of {{Europe}}},
  url = {http://ec.europa.eu/research/science-society/document_library/pdf_06/report-rocard-on-science-education_en.pdf},
  institution = {{European Commission}},
  urldate = {2014-04-11},
  date = {2007},
  author = {Rocard, Michel and Csermely, Peter and Jorde, Doris and Lenzen, Dieter and Walberg-Henriksson, Harriet and Hemmo, Valerie},
  file = {/home/jb/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/storage/7MI7FP5E/Rocard et al_2007_Science education now.pdf}
}

@article{winslow2006a,
  title = {Didaktiske Miljøer for Ligedannethed},
  journaltitle = {MONA},
  date = {2006},
  pages = {47},
  author = {Winsløw, Carl},
  file = {/home/jb/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/storage/87WN6W5U/Winsløw - 2006 - Didaktiske miljøer for ligedannethed}
}

@incollection{winslow2018,
  title = {Theorizing {{Lesson Study}}: {{Two}} Related Frameworks and Two {{Danish}} Case-Studies},
  booktitle = {({{To}} Appear) {{Mathematics Lesson Study Around}} the {{World}}: {{Theoretical}} and Methodological Issues},
  series = {Springer book series of ICME},
  publisher = {{Springer}},
  date = {2018},
  author = {Winsløw, Carl and Bahn, Jacob and Rasmussen, Klaus},
  editor = {Quaresma, Marisa and Winsløw, Carl and Clivaz, Stéphane and da Ponte, João and Ní Shúilleabháin, Aoibhinn and Takahashi, Akihiko},
  file = {/home/jb/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/storage/F6D2KSII/Winsløw et al. - 2018 - Theorizing Lesson Study Two related frameworks an.pdf}
}

@inproceedings{toshiakirafujii2015,
  location = {{Philippines}},
  title = {Lesson Study for Improving Quality  of  Mathematics  Education},
  url = {http://mathted.weebly.com/uploads/7/8/5/0/7850000/pp_41_to_48_ppd_toshiakira_fujii.pdf},
  eventtitle = {7th  {{ICMI}} - {{East Asia Regional Conference}} on {{Mathematics Education}}},
  urldate = {2017-06-20},
  date = {2015},
  author = {{Toshiakira Fujii}},
  file = {/home/jb/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/storage/Q9RK2C9K/Lesson study for improving quality  of  mathematics  education.pdf}
}
```